# Some question about even function

Tags: calculus

Given that $f$ is an even function, $f''(x)>0$. Which of the following are true?

I. $f(0)<f(1)$

II. $f(4)-f(3)<f(6)-f(5)$

III. $f(-2)<\frac{f(-3)+f(-1)}{2}$

I understand I is true since $f$ is increasing for $x>0$, and II is also true since $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$. How about III? Any hint for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\frac{f(-3)+f(-1)}2$ is the $y$-coordinate of the midpoint of the line segment whose endpoints are $\langle-3,f(-3)\rangle$ and $\langle-1,f(-1)\rangle$; the $x$-coordinate of that midpoint is clearly $-2$. And the curve is concave up, so ... ?

Comment: Because the curve is concave up, so the $y$-coordinate of the midpoint of the line segment must greater than the value of $f(-2)$! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sleepingip: You've got it. You're welcome!